# How to Rename Devices in Android Device Manager

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, device-manager

I'm currently working in a project with three Samsumg Galaxy Tabs in Android Studio.

When I run my App the Android Device Manager shows three identical devices. 
Is it possible to rename those devices so I'll know which one is which before starting the app?

Answer (score 0):

As of ADT revision 17, the device manufacturer and name appears after the serial number.

example:

```
[Nexus s: ....]
[LG bda: ....]
```

here is an image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPz6y.png

And some devices have a setting:

```
Homescreen -> press menu -> System settings -> applications -> development -> Device name
```

Here I can change the devices name which is shown in eclipse.

Unfortunately, my second development phone (Nexus-S, Stock rom with Android 2.3.4) does not have this setting - so maybe your phone has this setting...?!

Comment: _And some devices have a setting_   Thank you - that's exactly what I was looking for. 2 of the Galaxy Tabs are on Adnroid 4.4.2 and I was able to change the device name in the "System Information" settings. The device with Androoid 4.1.2 does not have this option.

Comment: -update- while the device is recognized by Windows with the updated device name, the Android Device Manager still shows three identical names for my Galaxy Tabs (Samsung-GT-N8000)

Comment: Have you tried to update your adt to revision 17? or it is already a higher version?

Comment: Also has you said the 4.1.2 device didn't worked. that happens with my Nexus-S as well. i think it might be a 4.4+ setting.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I use Android Studio Beta (0.8.2)